# disnake: Как создать текстовый канал в определённой категории?

Tags: python, disnake

У меня уже получилось создать канал в текущей категории, но что насчёт канала в определённой категории?

Вот код

```
@bot.event
async def on_modal_submit(inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
    if inter.custom_id == "creation_ticket":
        services = inter.text_values["label_1"]
        nick = inter.text_values["label_2_NICK"]
        await inter.send(f"Создаём тикет...")
        category = inter.channel.category
        channel = await inter.guild.create_text_channel(name="ticket", category=category)
        await inter.edit_original_response(f"Всё: {channel.id}")
```

Сначала я думал, что категорию которую disnake запрашивает можно получить по аналогии с get_channel() который принимает айди канала, чтобы уже управлять каналом, но с категориями я такого не нашёл

Answer (score 0):

```css
channel = await inter.guild.create_text_channel(name=f"{inter.author} тикет",category=guild.get_channel(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно получить категорию:

```py
category = disnake.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=ID)
```

`ID` нужно заменить на id нужной вам категории каналов.

После этого создаем канал с указанием категории, в моем случае это текстовый канал создаваемый в категории, полученную в переменную `category`:

```py
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name="channel", category=category)
```